# Flash video record on website tutorial

Tags: python, flash, video-capture, html5-video

I wanted to make a website that would let users record a small video message through their broswer and save it to my website.

As I have never used flash, i wanted to know what softwares would be required and what programming languages would I need? I mean, what should I go about learning to implement such a site. I would prefer open-source solutions wherever possible.

Can something like this be implemented using python and html5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many video solutions.  Here are two:

Take a look at Flash Media Server (FMS).  You will need to some server-side code to place the video into a folder as it streams up.

Also, if you're looking into free open-source take a look at Red5.